# Why not publish the voltdb.jar to maven repo?

Tags: voltdb

I only found that the voltdb client in the maven repo, but not fount the voltdb which contains the VoltProcedure.

It will be hard for me to manage the dependencies with maven, gradle or other tools.

Is there any deep reason for that? voltdb guys.

Answer (score 1):

I work at VoltDB.  We have a feature request ticket to add the voltdb-.jar to the maven repo, so there is no deep reason it is not there yet, only limited time and resources.

You may want to review our recently updated instructions for setting up Eclipse for running JUnit tests of stored procedures, or running procedures with the debugger.  It was recently moved to our examples/HOWTOs folder provided with the kit, and is available on github [here](https://github.com/VoltDB/voltdb/blob/master/examples/HOWTOs/EclipseUnitTestDebug.md).

Are you a working with anyone in our organization to evaluate VoltDB for a project?  We have Solution Architects that can assist you with technical issues if you'd like to contact us at info (at) voltdb (dot) com.

Best regards,
Ben